# Which command is used for the \thanks-command star?

Tags: symbols

I am looking for the command to produce the star which generates the `\thanks` command used within the `\author` command in the `article` class with `libertine` fonts.
Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tt=false, type1=true]{libertine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\author{Testauthor$^{*\star\ast}$\thanks{test}}
\title{Testtitle}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Here the relevant part of the pdf:

[image]

I am interested in star number four, so the star with five tips. Neither `*`, nor `\star`, nor `\ast` produces it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this symbol with `\textasteriskcentered`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tt=false, type1=true]{libertine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\author{Testauthor\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered}\thanks{test}}
\title{Testtitle}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, can you also explain why it only works with `\textsuperscript` and not with `^` in mathmode?

Comment: @Arne I have no idea, would have to look up its definition.